# Express rendering variable incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

Express rendering variable incorrectly. The correct url is:

> https://xxxx-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/5ba90b84-6fe4-4646-a80b-73ef5345aec1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY&Expires=1503682177&Signature=zw%2BYjpNAwh7IHfeuLlvKycJ7G9k%3D

Express render url below:

> https://xxxx-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/logos/5ba90b84-6fe4-4646-a80b-73ef5345aec1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY**&amp**;Expires=1503682177**&amp**;Signature=zw%2BYjpNAwh7IHfeuLlvKycJ7G9k%3D

The & characters are being rendered as **"&amp"**;
This is causing me problems.

Here's my code snippet:

```
  //...
  metaTag.image = company.logo;
  res.render('main.html', {metaTag:metaTag});
```

my html:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{metaTag.image}}" />
```

PS: If I get the log metaTag.image the url is correct. The problem is after the render

**Solution:**

After reviewing the documentation of my engine I found the solution. https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#autoescaping

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{metaTag.image | safe}}" />
```

Comment: Which templating engine?

Comment: You should edit out that AWS access key. Change it to ASDFACCESSKEY

Comment: The template is nunjucks

Comment: @agm1984 thanks, I redacted them for OP :D

Comment: Nice work. I was going to but I thought it would take a week for the edit to be approved.

Comment: If you now have a solution, then you should either post an answer to your own question (yes, you are allowed to do that) or delete your question.  You don't want to just leave an unanswered question sitting here when you already have the answer.